# Use a SHA1 from one project into another one

Tags: android, sha1, fingerprint

I am going to make a huge update in an app. It will connect to a new DB using new APIs, I will renew all the layouts, add some functionalities, remove others... so I am thinking on starting it from scratch because I will spend more time updating the old project than creating a new one.

The problem is that when I finish it I want to put it in google play instead of the old one and for that the fingerprint must match. So I need to create a new apk but with the fingerprint of the old one. Is that possible? Or otherwise is there a way to update a google play app with an apk with different apk?

Comment: The fingerprint is not of an app, but of a signing key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the keystore file that you used to sign the old app, the you just need to copy it to your new project and follow [these instructions](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) to sign your new apk with the old certificate.

Also, take into account that the package name of the new app *must* be the same you used in the old one.

Take a look at this blog post: [Things That Cannot Change](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html)